# Nginx Reverse Proxy Configuration Issue: Multiple Domains Redirected to Same Website

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl

I'm encountering an issue with my Nginx configuration where multiple domains are being redirected to the same website, despite having separate server blocks defined for each domain in the nginx config. I've gone through various troubleshooting steps, including checking configuration files, examining logs, and verifying DNS settings, but haven't been able to identify the root cause of the problem.

Details:

I have two domains: treseibert.com and wanderlog.treseibert.com.
Each domain should be served by a separate Node.js application running on different ports (3001 and 3000, respectively).
I've configured Nginx to serve these domains with SSL/TLS termination and reverse proxy to the corresponding Node.js applications.
However, when I try to access either domain, both domains redirect me to the website served by the Node.js application running on port 3000.

```
    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for treseibert.com and www.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name treseibert.com www.treseibert.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for wanderlog.treseibert.com and www.wanderlog.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name wanderlog.treseibert.com www.wanderlog.treseibert.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server block for treseibert.com and www.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name treseibert.com www.treseibert.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key1.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # Additional SSL settings can be added here if needed
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

# HTTPS server block for wanderlog.treseibert.com and www.wanderlog.treseibert.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name wanderlog.treseibert.com www.wanderlog.treseibert.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key1.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # Additional SSL settings can be added here if needed
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Steps Taken:

Checked Nginx configuration files (/etc/nginx/sites-available) for syntax errors and correctness.
Verified DNS settings to ensure that each domain points to the correct server IP address.
Examined Nginx error and access logs (/var/log/nginx/error.log and /var/log/nginx/access.log) for any clues, but found no relevant entries.
Reviewed firewall rules (iptables -L) to ensure that traffic to necessary ports (80 and 443) is allowed.
Investigated network configuration (ifconfig and ip addr show) to confirm correct network settings.
Ensured that there are no conflicting entries in the /etc/hosts file.
Temporarily disabled SSL configuration in Nginx to see if it affects the behavior, but the issue persisted.
Changed the port in one of the server blocks to test if the issue is related to port configuration, but the behavior remained the same.

Additionally there are no error logs from nginx.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: your website is not up and running, first make sure its working, I tried to access it and its having ssl problems

Comment: The website is up and running, you may have accessed it when I was messing with configuration. You can take another look at it now.

Comment: you have issue in your firewall, what firewall do you have ?

Comment: did you set up cloudflare with your dns ?

Comment: I use ufw and I do have cloudflare for dns. I have A records setup for root and wanderlog they both point to my raspberry pi webserver. I have ports 22, 80, 443, 3000, and 3001 open.

Comment: your issue is not in nginx, your issue is within network, you can private message me I will give you access to a PC for trouble shooting your issue because it needs a lot of talking.

Comment: Just to make sure it's network issue, try to setup one domain in nginx without any other domain , if it works then the issue is not network, but if it did not work then the issue is network which am sure is your case 100%

Comment: most probably its fw issue that's my guess or something has to do with cloudflare

Comment: also , try to make your website work under http when you try nginx , for now, just use http, if it works, then I can tell you what is your problem

Comment: it wont let me pm you, could you pm me.I appreciate the help!

Comment: email me at ahmedaminshahin@gmail.com